# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'store.getState')

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, redux

I'm following the [Let’s Build: Cryptocurrency Native Mobile App With React Native + Redux](https://medium.com/react-native-training/bitcoin-ripple-ethereum-price-checker-with-react-native-redux-e9d076037092) tutorial.

When I create my store in `App.js`, the app works fine

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import devTools from 'remote-redux-devtools';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Platform, View } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import promise from 'redux-promise';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import logger from 'redux-logger';

import { Header, CryptoContainer } from './src/components';
import rootReducer from './src/reducers';    

const middleware = applyMiddleware(thunk, promise, logger);

const Store = createStore(rootReducer, compose(middleware, devTools({
  name: Platform.OS,
  hostname: 'localhost',
  port: 5678
}), ));

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={Store}>
        <View>
          <Header />
          <CryptoContainer />
        </View>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

but when I move the store logic to a new file `./src/Store.js`,

```
import { Platform } from 'react-native';    
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import devTools from 'remote-redux-devtools';
import promise from 'redux-promise';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import logger from 'redux-logger';

import rootReducer from './reducers';

const middleware = applyMiddleware(thunk, promise, logger);

const Store = createStore(rootReducer,compose(middleware,devTools({
            name: Platform.OS,
            hostname: 'localhost',
            port: 5678
        }),
    )
);

export default Store;
```

and use it in `App.js` like

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import { Header, CryptoContainer } from './src/components';
import { Store } from './src/Store';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={Store}>
        <View>
          <Header />
          <CryptoContainer />
        </View>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

I get

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'store.getState')

What's causing my build (`expo start`) to fail when I import `Store.js`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It seems the import statement is not right. It should be:

```
import Store from './src/Store';
```

Answer (score 7):

if you're importing a `single named export` 
e.g where you've done `export const MyComponent = () => {}` you'd import it like 
 `import { MyComponent } from "./MyComponent"`

if you're importing a `default export` 
 e.g where you've done `const MyComponent = () => {} export default MyComponent` you'd import it like 
 `import MyDefaultComponent from "./MyDefaultExport"`

Comment: Can you explain that further? Why should one do that, and what is hidden behind the dots?

Comment: Please add all relevant information to the answer, not to the comment section

Answer (score 1):

I got this error because I was exporting the wrong component from my main App file.

I was exporting this:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation'
import Navigator from './src/components/Navigator'
import { store } from './src/store'

const App = createAppContainer(Navigator);

const Wrapped = props => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
)

export default Provider; // wrong!
```

That last line should be:

```
export default Wrapped; // right!
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Itunu Adekoya shows that you can decide how you want to export / import, and in this case about personal preference, as there isn't a perf difference.

In the case where you have a lot of exports from a file, and perhaps some are unrelated or won't all  be used together, it is better to export them individual as consts and then in other file only import what you need via import { } format, this will be sure to only include relevant imprts

Answer (score 1):

in my case its casing & named import issue. imported as

```
import store from './Redux/Store'
```

it should be

```
import {Store} from './Redux/Store'
```