# Redux - Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'store.getState')

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I'm learning reactNative and I cannot resolve an error. In the tutorial I'm following, we want to allow user to be able to add (or remove) movie to favourites and for that we are using Redux. After implementing the code when launch (through Expo Go on android), I've got the following error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'store.getState'). Thanks
Reducers:

```
// Store/Reducers/favoriteReducer.js

const initialState = { favoritesFilm: [] }

function toggleFavorite(state = initialState, action) {
  let nextState
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'TOGGLE_FAVORITE':
      const favoriteFilmIndex = state.favoritesFilm.findIndex(item => item.id === action.value.id)
      if (favoriteFilmIndex !== -1){
        nextState = {
          ...state,
          favoritesFilm: state.favoritesFilm.filter( (item, index) => index !== favoriteFilmIndex )
        }
      }
      else{
        nextState = {
          ...state,
          favoritesFilm: [...state.favoritesFilm, action.value]
        }
      }
      return nextState || state
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default toggleFavorite
```

Store configure:

```
// Store/configureStore.js

import { createStore } from 'redux';
import toggleFavorite from './Reducers/favoriteReducer'

export default createStore(toggleFavorite)
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Navigation from './Navigation/Navigation';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { Store } from './Store/configureStore';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <Provider store={Store}>
        <Navigation/>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

Film detail

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, ActivityIndicator, ScrollView, Image } from 'react-native'
import { getFilmDetailFromApi, getImageFromApi } from '../API/TMDBApi'
import moment from 'moment'
import numeral from 'numeral'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class FilmDetail extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      film: undefined,
      isLoading: true
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    getFilmDetailFromApi(this.props.navigation.state.params.idFilm).then(data => {
      this.setState({
        film: data,
        isLoading: false
      })
    })
  }

  _displayLoading() {
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.loading_container}>
          <ActivityIndicator size='large' />
        </View>
      )
    }
  }

  _displayFilm() {
    const { film } = this.state
    if (film != undefined) {
      return (
        <ScrollView style={styles.scrollview_container}>
          <Image
            style={styles.image}
            source={{uri: getImageFromApi(film.backdrop_path)}}
          />
          <Text style={styles.title_text}>{film.title}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.description_text}>{film.overview}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.default_text}>Sorti le {moment(new Date(film.release_date)).format('DD/MM/YYYY')}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.default_text}>Note : {film.vote_average} / 10</Text>
          <Text style={styles.default_text}>Nombre de votes : {film.vote_count}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.default_text}>Budget : {numeral(film.budget).format('0,0[.]00 $')}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.default_text}>Genre(s) : {film.genres.map(function(genre){
              return genre.name;
            }).join(" / ")}
          </Text>
          <Text style={styles.default_text}>Companie(s) : {film.production_companies.map(function(company){
              return company.name;
            }).join(" / ")}
          </Text>
        </ScrollView>
      )
    }
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props)
    return (
      <View style={styles.main_container}>
        {this._displayLoading()}
        {this._displayFilm()}
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  main_container: {
    flex: 1
  },
  loading_container: {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  scrollview_container: {
    flex: 1
  },
  image: {
    height: 169,
    margin: 5
  },
  title_text: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 35,
    flex: 1,
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    marginLeft: 5,
    marginRight: 5,
    marginTop: 10,
    marginBottom: 10,
    color: '#000000',
    textAlign: 'center'
  },
  description_text: {
    fontStyle: 'italic',
    color: '#666666',
    margin: 5,
    marginBottom: 15
  },
  default_text: {
    marginLeft: 5,
    marginRight: 5,
    marginTop: 5,
  }
})

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    favoritesFilm: state.favoritesFilm
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(FilmDetail)
```

Package.json

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.3",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.3",
    "expo": "~40.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.3",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "numeral": "^2.0.6",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-40.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.8.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.13.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.9",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.15.2",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.0",
    "@types/react": "~16.9.35",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.63.2"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

UPDATE: changing `import { Store } from './Store/configureStore';` to `import Store from './Store/configureStore';` in App.js makes it work
Already answer here: [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'store.getState')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53737943/typeerror-undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-store-getstate)

Comment: So you get an error `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'store.getState')` yet there is no code posted in your question that does `store.getState`. If this error is from 3rd party code then you can look up the call stack and try to find out what line in your code produced this error. If you don't know React or Redux then it would be easier to create a web app as they are easier to debug. Once your logic is working you can try to create a native app from it.

Comment: Thanks I will try to read the call stack and update some third party

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to change
Store config:

```
export const store = createStore(toggleFavorite)
```

now you can import like this

```
import { store } from './Store/configureStore';
```

In mapStateToProps add (toggleFavorite) reducer where, that (favoritesFilm) state is present

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    favoritesFilm: state.toggleFavorite.favoritesFilm
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. After changing the `import { Store } from './Store/configureStore';` to  `import Store from './Store/configureStore';` it's working

Comment: thanks for identifying currect issue @John